# Not getting dropdown element from database

Tags: php

I want 2 dropdown lists:

1. university
2. college

If someone select the university according to that college name is shown to the user in second dropdown list and  One more thing both university and college name are stored in one table like

```
id,University_name,College_name
```

and we have fetch data from that only

```php
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hr");
    $query="SELECT DISTINCT University_Name FROM university";
    $result =$mysqli->query($query);
    $options="";
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        $University_Name = $row["University_Name"];
        $options .= "<OPTION VALUE=\"$University_Name\" name='customer_email'>".$University_Name.'</option>';
    }
?>

<div class="input-row">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <label class="control-label">University Name <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
        <select name="university" id="university" class="form-control"  onchange="contrychange()" required>
            <option value="Select university">Select University</option>
            <?=$options?>
        </select>
       </div>
</div>

<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hr");
    $query="SELECT College_Name FROM university where University_Name='$University_Name'";
    $result =$mysqli->query($query);
    $options="";
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        $College_Name = $row["College_Name"];
        $options .= "<OPTION VALUE=\"$College_Name\" name='customer_email'>".$College_Name.'</option>';
    }
?>

<div class="input-row">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <label class="control-label" for="field_12">College Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
        <select name="college" id="college" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="Select college">Select College</option>
            <?=$options?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use ajax call to fetch the collage data from table & set into the <select> element

Comment: use javascript ajax

Comment: Assuming that you want to create cascading dropdown list. Please refer this example. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2pza5/

Comment: If you don't want to use AJAX requests you will have to re-render the page after the user makes a choice using a GET or POST request to pass along the data to allow you to query the database.

Comment: you can check out my answer, and upvote if you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdown list are being populated as the page is being loaded, just put the foreach loop in between the select tag.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hr");
$query="SELECT DISTINCT University_Name FROM university";
$result =$mysqli->query($query);
?>

<div class="input-row">
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<label class="control-label">University Name <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
    <select name="university" id="university" class="form-control"  onchange="contrychange()" required>
        <option value="Select university">Select University</option>
         <?php
         while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
               $University_Name = $row["University_Name"];
               echo "<option value=\"$University_Name\" name='customer_email'>".$University_Name."</option>";
         }
         ?>
    </select>
   </div>
```

Do this step with the college drop down as well. It's pretty straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Change this line like this inside loop
`$options .= "<OPTION VALUE=".$College_Name." name=\"customer_email\">".$College_Name."</option>";`